# Centering a div with floated elements

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing floated links. I applied the property and value of 'width:auto' to the div. But, for some reason the div is taking up the entire line, instead of just presuming the total width of the floated elements. What am I doing wrong?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/X9anU/3/

CSS:

```
#user-links {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
height: auto;
width: auto;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
overflow: auto;
}

.user-link {
float: left;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.user-link a {
text-decoration: none;
font-family: calibri;
font-size: 16px;
color: #fff;
}

.user-link a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using div's instead of an unordered list?  With unordered list you can use display: inline-block then text-align: center to centers LI's inside the UL

Answer (score 3):

Just because you set the left/right margins to `auto` doesn't mean your div will collapse.

The floated children also won't cause for it to collapse on the horizontal axis.

If you're trying to center the links, you can set the links to `display: inline-block;`, remove the floats, and apply `text-align: center;` to the `#user-links` div.

Like this:

```
#user-links {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.user-link {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/X9anU/13/

Answer (score 1):

Well that is the default behaviour of [block-level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes) - they take up 100% width unless you specify one, regardless of the display value of their descendants. You also can't center an element with auto left/right margins *without* specifying a width.

Give an explicit width to `#user-links`

http://jsfiddle.net/X9anU/6/

Answer (score 1):

A `<div>` is a block level element by default which will span the width of the parent unless otherwise specified, in this case, width: auto is assuming the width of the parent container.

If you would like the `#user-links` element to only span the width of the content and be centered within it's container, you'll need to assign `display: table` to the `#user-links` declaration in your CSS:

```
#user-links {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X9anU/16/

Here's the list of browsers that support `display: table`: http://caniuse.com/css-table

Answer (score 0):

**Try**:

```
width: 960px;
```

People mostly uses 960px as the size of websites, especially in photoshop using the grid system, since it'll fit in mostly any size of monitor. Any other number is also possible.

The elements inside the div with `fixed width` will be in the center since the `margin-left` and `margin-right` is set to `auto`.

An example of [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X9anU/3/) using `width: 500px;` just to show you the difference.

Comment: There is no "safe" size.  New devices are coming out all the time with different resolutions, you can't expect them all to have 960px available.